# gaphql API is not working in IE edge and IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, angular9

The graphql url is not working and not fetching the data in both IE edge and IE 11 browsers. I am usiong Angular 9 application and have installed `classlist.js` and `web-animations.js` from polyfills.ts.

**IE Edge Issue below:**
[image]

**IE 11 issue:**
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please provide [a nimimal, reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With only the above screenshot, we can't locate the issue. With some code which can reproduce the issue, we can have a test and see how to help.